# Perl Win32::OLE Generating Access Database

Tags: perl, ms-access

**Description:**  I am reading from a list of flat files and generating and loading an access database. Windows XP, Perl 5.8.8, and no access to additional modules outside the default installed.

**Issue(s):** Performance, Performance, Performance. It is taking ~20 minutes to load in all of the data. I am assuming that there might be a better way to load the data rather than addnew & update.

**Logic:** Without posting a lot of my transformations and additional logic here is what I am attempting:

1. Open file x
2. read row 0 of file x
3. jet->execute a Create statement from string dervied from step 2
4. read in rows 1 - n creating a tab delimitted string and store into an array
5. Open a recordset using select * from tablename
6. for each item in array

   1. recordset->AddNew
   2. split the item based on the tab

      1. for each item in the split

         1. rs->Fields->Item(pos)->{Value} = item_value
   3. recordset->Update

Comment: How many rows get loaded in the 20 minutes? How many columns (fields) in each row?  How big in bytes is the input file altogether?  Are you creating indices during load?

Answer (score 2):

One issue in slow loads is doing a commit on every update.  Make sure that automatic commits are off and do one every 1000 rows or whatever.  If it is not a gigantic load, don't do them at all.  Also, do not create indexes during the load, create them afterwards.

Also, I'm not sure that OLE is the best way to do this.  I load Access db's all of the time using DBI and Win32::ODBC.  Goes pretty fast.

Per request, here is sample load program, did about 100k records per minute on WinXP, Access 2003, ActiveState Perl 5.8.8.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Win32::ODBC;

$| = 1;

my $dsn = "LinkManagerTest";
my $db = new Win32::ODBC($dsn)
    or die "Connect to database $dsn failed: " . Win32::ODBC::Error();

my $rows_added = 0;
my $error_code;

while (<>) {
    chomp;

    print STDERR "."     unless $. % 100;
    print STDERR " $.\n" unless $. % 5000;

    my ($source, $source_link, $url, $site_name) = split /\t/;

    my $insert = qq{
        insert into Links (
            URL,
            SiteName,
            Source,
            SourceLink
        )
        values (
            '$url',
            '$site_name',
            '$source',
            '$source_link'
        )
    };

    $error_code = $db->Sql($insert);

    if ($error_code) {
        print "\nSQL update failed on line $. with error code $error_code\n";
        print "SQL statement:\n$insert\n\n";
        print "Error:\n" . $db->Error() . "\n\n";
    }
    else {
        $rows_added++;
    }

    $db->Transact('SQL_COMMIT') unless $. % 1000;
}

$db->Transact('SQL_COMMIT');
$db->Close();

print "\n";
print "Lines Read: $.\n";
print "Rows Added: $rows_added\n";

exit 0;
```

Comment: The load is larger than what I would like for an access databse.. I believe I am loading roughly 300k rows. Can you pm me a sample of your dbi code?